# Nestjs + Graphql multiple endpoints issue with first code approach

Tags: api, graphql, nestjs

Despite the search of different issues about this, the bug seems to still keep on existing.
I tried to create a couple of graphQL endpoints, to split admin and "public" resolvers.

In my app.module.ts

```
ProfileModule,
AdminProfileModule,
GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      debug: config.isDev(),
      playground: true,
      autoSchemaFile: join(process.cwd(), 'src/schema.gql'),
      context: ({ req }) => ({ req }),
      transformAutoSchemaFile: true,
      include: [
        ProfileModule,
      ],
    }),
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      debug: config.isDev(),
      playground: true,
      autoSchemaFile: join(process.cwd(), 'src/admin.gql'),
      context: ({ req }) => ({ req }),
      transformAutoSchemaFile: true,
      include: [
        AdminProfileModule,
      ],
    }),
```

While trying to debug I noticed that just the fact to add a `GraphQLModule.forRoot`, even with an empty includes array, even when not injecting AdminProfileModule, generated the following error :

`Schema must contain uniquely named types but contains multiple types named Links`

ProfileModule and AdminProfileModule share some schemas, but two resolvers are different but with queries handling same name. For design reasons, I don't wanna change the names.

I think the bug is due to the fact that GraphQL.forRoot doesn't dive into "includes" modules, but check out for all imported modules.

Could you check it out??

Thanks.

Comment: This is a very known issue https://github.com/nestjs/graphql/issues/721