# Expose two endpoints in Graphql NestJS

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs

I tried the following logic to expose two GraphQL endpoints in my NestJS application, but I encountered some problems. I want to use the same application and types for both. Any advice or a fix would be greatly appreciated.

`error`

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Schema must contain uniquely named types but contains multiple types named "Province".
```

`app.module.ts`

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      path: "/graphql",
      autoSchemaFile: { path: 'schema.gql' },
    }),
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      path: "/graphql-public",
      autoSchemaFile: { path: 'schema2.gql' },
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Seems to be the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74115549/nestjs-graphql-multiple-endpoints-issue-with-first-code-approach